# How to split file with spaces in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a file.txt. The text data is as below:

> N01 Langkawi,1,1000,2,3000
>
> P002 Sungai Air Tawar,1,300,2,900

I know that each data can be split using the comma ','.
But i want to read

> P002 Sungai Air Tawar

as two different data. The first bit with the number infront is the code, whereas the other bit is the name of place.

Do i need to use 'space' as delimeter? Im sorry for bad english

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: use Apache CSV https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very quick and dirty way of doing it:

```
String s = "P002 Sungai Air Tawar";
String one = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));
String two = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
System.out.println("one: " + one);
System.out.println("two: " + two);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could just use `indexOf(",")` to get the first index of the comma. Then you can just `"P002 Sungai Air Tawar,1,300,2,900".substring(indexOf(","))` to get the first part of the string.

Similarly you can use substring again and split by the comma to get the second part of the arguments.

```
 String input = "P002 Sungai Air Tawar,1,300,2,900";
 int index = input.indexOf(",");
 String name = input.substring(0, index + 1);
 String[] args = input.substring(index + 1).split(",");
```

Comment: you mean space instead of comma?